# How to show File reference as <img tag in HTML using Angular?

Tags: html, angular

Controller.ts has:

```
img: File = someFile; // That I know is img some kind of img, png, jpg....
```

HTML:

**How can I show the file in an img tag?**

Comment: something like: `<img [src]="img">`?

Comment: Great thanks! I was almost there :) tried <img [src]={{img}}> but it was obviously wrong. Being noob on angular + finding lot of stuff with old/new syntax makes it a bit confusing for me xD Sorry for simple question. Thanks for fast reply!

Comment: Hmm. it stops working when I select a new file using input (change)....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve that with one way data-binding.
In Angular you can bind to any HTML property by adding [] to the property.
Is preferred to save an image in the assets folder, if you arent downloading the image.
EXAMPLE:
***************TS FILE********************
...

```
this.imgURL = 'assets/img/path';
```

...
***************HTML FILE********************
...

```
<img [src]="imgURL">
```

...